# Write program that runs during Windows boot - such as chkdsk?

Tags: windows, winapi, boot

Programs like ScanDisk/chkdsk can run while Windows is booting, i.e. before the logon screen appears. I thought this was only for Windows internal programs, but I have seen that Avast! antivirus offers the same feature, to perform virus checks while Windows is not yet loaded. How is this accomplished? I.e. what kind of APIs do I have to use to write such a program? Can it be any kind of commandline program, am I restricted to a subset of the Windows API, do I have to implement a specific interface?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447.aspx

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks a lot! And for future readers of this question: I have just found http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/ which is a kind of documentation for the undocumented functions of ntdll.lib and will probably be very helpful for anyone trying to write a native program

Comment: Also helpful: A native demo program by Mark Russinovich http://read.pudn.com/downloads69/sourcecode/windows/system/247175/Native/NATIVE.C__.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at registry key

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager**

And value of **BootExecute**

More info here :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963230.aspx

Comment: Thanks, have you maybe got some more info for a programmer's point of view, i.e. what kind of APIs I have to use to write such a program? Can it be any kind of commandline program, am I restricted to a subset of the Windows API, do I have to implement a specific interface?

Comment: You don't even get the Windows API.  You are restricted to the native API, and probably only a subset of it.